# Most performant copy-less mapping of a void* pointer to a struct packed?

Tags: c++, struct, memory-alignment, strict-aliasing

I have a function returning a pointer `void*` I know is at least 64b/8B aligned.

My question is **exclusively** toward:

- `gcc version >5`
- single endianness (**x86_64 as little-endian**)
- not interested in compatibility
- C++ 11 only (up to C++14) eventually old and new ABI

The raw data comes from an external device via a driver.

```cpp
struct myStruct {
    std::uint16_t B3;
    std::uint16_t B2;
    std::uint16_t B1;
    std::uint32_t A;
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

I should be able to access each member without any problem such as **strict aliasing or alignment**.

```cpp
struct myStruct* parsed_data=nullptr;
parsed_data = static_cast<struct myStruct*>(getRawDataVoid());

uint16_t a = parsed_data.A;
```

The following is however forbidden:

```cpp
struct myStruct* parsed_data=nullptr;
parsed_data = static_cast<struct myStruct*>(getRawDataVoid());

uint16_t *a = &parsed_data->A; // this is forbidden
```

I know this is (was?) used a lot in C for parser/network analyzer or any application taking raw data to parse it copy-lessly. Especially in embedded system.

### Question A

- Is there any new way of doing so?

---

### Question B

```cpp
struct myStruct {
    std::uint16_t B3;
    std::uint16_t B2;
    std::uint16_t B1;
    std::uint8_t text[25];
} __attribute__((__packed__));

struct myStruct* parsed_data=nullptr;
parsed_data = static_cast<struct myStruct*>(getRawDataVoid());

uint8_t *text_ptr = parsed_data->text;
```

I would need to access the pointer of `text` to convert it to std::string for normal C++ code.

- What can be the problem with the text member?
- Even though `text` is an array, I don't think the struct pointer must be aligned on 25B (25x uint8_t). Right?

I believe there is no problem because the array is an `uint8_t/char`.

- Do you confirm?

#### Source: Accessing packed members from a structure

This is for ARM but GCC x86_64 has the same feature.

- https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_intro/armclang_intro_xxq1474359912082.htm

> If a member of a structure or union is packed and therefore does not
> have its natural alignment, then to access this member, **you must use
> the structure or union that contains this member**. You must not take
> the address of such a packed member to use as a pointer, because the
> pointer might be unaligned. **Dereferencing such a pointer can be unsafe**
> even when unaligned accesses are supported by the target, because
> certain instructions always require word-aligned addresses.

Comment: A safe way would be to use `memcpy`, which is typically recognized by compilers and optimized into a fast machine code without any unnecessary overhead. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/bvTTd7Gvr.

Comment: Thanks! Accessing packed struct members is safe. My question is about copy-less, fast machine code doesn't mean fast memory access.

Comment: The problem is that you don't show what you want do to with the stored values. Once you do anything with them, they very likely will need to be "copied" from memory to registers. What do you mean by _copy-less_ then? See this live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/oro8GGaGG. There are no copies back into memory, only loads, which are always necessary when you need to access the stored values.

Comment: If a single member is accessed, only that member will be copied, not the whole packed structure. Also, the raw data is located in memory(+volatile), not cache. Your solution is good but all the offsets need to be set manually; the compiler does it for me with a packed structure. A single `static_cast` and I'm good. If I'm wrong, please provide something I can refer to. I forgot to mention, that's more or less for a library.

Comment: Moving your whole data structure by pointer/reference isn't an option?